# django-cors-header not working as expected when using Postman

Tags: django, python-3.x, reactjs, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I'm trying to use my DRF API in my React Web App with Axios but I'm getting CORS policy blocked.

I've checked the headers using POSTMAN and seems like django-cors-header is  not actually embedding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

This is my settings.py from Django:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'trvl',
    'rest_framework',
    'coreapi',
    'django_filters',
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False
```

And this is what I get from POSTMAN

[image]

How can I fix this so every response has the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *`

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same scenario as you.  Same frontend and backend.

I was able to resolve my issue by adding this to my settings.py in addition to everything you listed.

```
CORS_REPLACE_HTTPS_REFERER = True
```

Answer (score 0):

In settings.py
set `ALLOWED_HOSTS = []` to `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).